# WPF: The bottom line of Label in DataGrid is disappeared

Tags: wpf, text, datagrid, label, line

I have a DataGrid and I set DataGrid.Columns combined with many DataGridTemplateColumn.

One of DataGridTemplateColumn needs to show FileName.

I use Label in DataTemplate and binding FileName, and Label's ToolTip also Binding the same FileName.

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Data.ImageNameStrings, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Width="50" MinWidth="48">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding FileName}">
                                <Label.ToolTip>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" Padding="6,2" Background="White" Foreground="#353535" FontSize="14"/>
                                </Label.ToolTip>
                            </Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I expect it will show the same result, but when the filename has a bottom line, the label content's bottom line disappears.

The tooltip is correct.

[image]

Next, I try the filename that has two bottom lines, it will lose one bottom line.

[image]

What is going on?

Why bottom line disappears?

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **Underscore** (not bottom line). You can use `TextBlock` instead of `Label`.

```
<TextBlock Content="{Binding FileName}">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" Padding="6,2" Background="White" Foreground="#353535" FontSize="14"/>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Underscore is used in `Lable` as shortcut, take a look at this example

```
<Button Width="100" Command="{Binding ClickMeCommand}">
    <Label Content="Click_Me" />
</Button>
```

Here, the button will look like this

[image]

and if you press on `m` key on your keyboard, the command will be executed.

Comment: It is perfect what I want, Thanks! 
And I understand it is Underscore.